# Check if value of one array is found in another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know if this type of comparison is possible. I am trying to compare arrays like listed below.

```
$array = ["User1-2", "User2-2", "User3-2", "User4-2"];

$array2 = ["User1-2:280", "User2-2:280", "User3-2:280", "User4-2:280"];
```

result for User1-2 would be 280, and it should be printed as result

Comment: what is with your [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622200/compare-two-arrays-and-then-return-the-index-of-the-difference) question? it looks similar with less code and same missing explanation why you like to get that waht you want.

Comment: What's the format for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simlpy cycle through the second array, split at `:`, check the first part and, in case of a match, return the second

```js
function findX(value, arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var toSplit = arr[i].split(':');
    if (toSplit[0] === value) {
      return toSplit[1];
     }
  }
}

console.log(findX("User1-2", ["User1-2:280", "User2-2:280", "User3-2:280", "User4-2:280"]));
```

Comment: It displays error Uncaught TypeError: arr[i].split is not a function

Comment: From the snippet? Because in here it works fine.

Comment: If you copied and pasted just the body of the function of course you'll need to adapt it (e.g., instead of `arr` you should write `$array2` if your code looks like the one in your question).

Comment: I just tested it in chrome and it works fine. Are you sure you're calling it correctly and with the same parameters? Because from the looks of the error it seems like your array doesn't contain strings.

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a specific answer format, so here is a simple implementation which goes through all elements from the first array and checks if the second array has a value which starts with it.

```
var $array = ["User1-2", "User2-2", "User3-2", "User4-2"];

var $array2 = ["User1-2:280", "User2-2:280", "User3-2:280", "User4-2:280"];

$array.forEach(x=> {
    var found = $array2.find(x=>x.startsWith(x));
    if (!!found) {
        console.log(x, found.split(':')[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: yep, fixing now

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work!

```
var $array = ["User1-2", "User2-2", "User3-2", "User4-2"];

var $array2 = ["User1-2:280", "User2-2:280", "User3-2:280", "User4-2:280"];

$array.forEach(element1=>{
  console.log(element1, $array2.find(element2=>element2.indexOf(element1)>-1).substring(element1.length+1))
})
```